# Undefined reference to 'gtk_source_buffer_new' and 'gtk_source_view_new_with_buffer' Error

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I installed gtk and took care of path by adding symbolic link in /include. I am building a project using it. when i try to compile it by 
"gcc project.c -o project_gtk $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)"
am getting "Undefined reference to 'gtk_source_buffer_new' and 'gtk_source_view_new_with_buffer' Error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please include the output of running `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`. "took care of path by adding symbolic link in /include". That sounds dodgey. If gtk was installed properly you should not need any hacks like that.

Comment: When i installed gtk, some of the headers created in sub-directory and i got error. so i created symbolic link from those sub-directory.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about those initial errors to fix it properly instead of applying a hack as that could be a source of your problems. And please provide the requested `pkg-config` output.

Comment: I added pkg-config output, But error remains. I think there are some installation errors. May be i should reinstall. Would you mind suggesting any command to completely remove gtk

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_source_buffer_new()` and `gtk_source_view_new_with_buffer()` are not part of GTK+; they are part of [GtkSourceView](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView), which is a separate project entirely. You will need to add that package to your `pkg-config` invocation as well (it should be `gtksourceview-3.0`).